# why it say "the action cannot be completed because the file is open in python“？

Tags: python, windows

```
def main_loop():
    global errname, errtime, error_detail, conclusion
    error_detail = ""
    facts_all = {}
    facts = []
    buffer = 0
    current_time = datetime.now()

    while os.path.exists("C:\Winusr"):
        print(paths["wintrace"])
        try:
            start_point = 0
            old_size = os.path.getsize(paths["wintrace"])
            while os.path.getsize(paths["wintrace"])>= old_size:
                #fo = open(paths["wintrace"], "rb")
                #fo.seek(start_point,1)
                shutil.copyfile(paths["wintrace"], "C:\Winusr\wintrace1.log")
                fo = open("C:\Winusr\wintrace1.log", "rb")
                fo.seek(start_point, 1)
                errtime = datetime(1900, 1, 1)
                old_size = os.path.getsize(paths["wintrace"])
                #start from here
                for line in fo.readlines():
                    line = str(line.decode('ISO-8859-1'))
                    print(line)
                    if fnmatch.fnmatch(line, "*START DUMP LOG BUFFER*"):
                        buffer = 1
                    if fnmatch.fnmatch(line, "*END DUMP LOG BUFFER*"):
                        buffer = 0
                    if buffer == 1:
                        continue

                    facts_all = collect_facts(line,facts_all,key_string,key_value_dic)
                    for pattern in error_detect:
                        if fnmatch.fnmatch(line, pattern):
                            try:
                                err_type = df[df["Error Detect Keyword"] == pattern]["Err Type"].to_string(index=False).lstrip()
                                errname = df[df["Err Type"] == err_type]["Error Name"].tolist()[0].lstrip()

                                errtime = datetime.strptime(
                                datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(paths["wintrace"])).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + " " + line[:8], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") #"%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S"
                                #errtime = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(paths["wintrace"])).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + " " + line[:8]
                                #errtime = errtime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                                product = re.findall(r"[/](.+?)[.]", paths["cur"])
                                product = product[0].split("/")[-1]
                                tester = tester_name(paths["cur"])
                                if len(facts_all) != 0:
                                    facts.append(errname)
                                    #idex = 9999
                                    for fact, line in facts_all.items():
                                        if fact in dic1[errname]:
                                            error_detail = error_detail + line + '\n'
                                            facts.append(fact)
                                    print("err_detail1", error_detail)
                                    if len(facts) != 1:
                                        facts = list(set(facts))
                                        conclusion = inference_engine(facts)
                                        print("errtime", errtime)
                                        print("current_time", current_time)
                                        if conclusion != "cannot find solution for this error" and errtime > current_time:
                                            solutions = sop2(errlist, errname, conclusion)
                                            row = recording(tester, product, errname, errtime, error_detail, conclusion)
                                            print("gg pop out GUI!!!")
                                            #send_email(errname, errtime, tester, error_detail)
                                            GUI(errname, errtime, error_detail, conclusion, solutions, row)
                                            current_time = datetime.now()                                 
                                            workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(r"G:\expert system data\Machine Database.xls")
                                            workbook1 = copy(workbook)
                                            ws1 = workbook1.get_sheet(0)
                                            style = xlwt.XFStyle()
                                            style.num_format_str = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'
                                            ws1.write(row, 8, current_time, style)
                                            workbook1.save(r"G:\expert system data\Machine Database.xls")
                                            error_detail = ""
                                            facts_all = {}
                                            facts = []
                                    error_detail = ""
                                    facts_all = {}
                                    facts = []
                            except:
                                continue

                start_point = fo.tell()
                fo.close()
        except:
            continue
    else:
        main_loop()
```

the paths["wintrace"] is ""C:\Winusr\Wintrace.log", i dont want it is open cause sometimes need to change its name or delete, i copy this file and open the copied one, but it still show it is open, can u help me check where it is opened? besides, i use "filepath = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()", but dont think it will open the wintrace file.[the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeI0Y.png)

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1966/how-do-you-find-what-process-is-holding-a-file-open-in-windows

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use `with open(...) as f` to open a file, to make sure it is always closed. Also, make the code within that context as small as possible, to close it as soon as possible.

Comment: convert all your uses of `open` to use `with open`. You may be leaving files open from previous runs or other programs, especially if it throws an exception. The with will cause another level of indentation, so consider breaking up your code into a few functions to make it easier to read.

Comment: But i never open the original wintrace file, i just cope it and open the copied one, why it say the original file is opened, sorry i dont understand where i open this file

Comment: I use resource monitor to check, shows original file not in process, but when i want to rename it still show open in python...